# Comparing dictionaries and creating new dictionary with values in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, generic-collections

I have two dictionaries Dic A &  Dic B. Dic A & Dic B have same keys . I would like to move the values in both the dictionaries into a new dictionary (with Value from Dic A being the key in new dictionary).  I couldnt figure out a way in merging or intersecting the two dictionaries to get a new one. What would be the right approach in getting the desired output

```
Dic A
=======

A1   Val 1
A2   Val 2
A3   Val 3

Dic B
========

A1  Cat 1
A2  Cat 2 
A3  Cat 3
```

Desired Result

```
Dic C
=======

Val 1  Cat 1 
Val 2  Cat 2 
Val 3  Cat 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sounds like a join on the two original ones, followed by a conversion:

```
var merged = dicA.Join(dicB, pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Key,
                       (a, b) => new { Key = a.Value, Value = b.Value })
                 .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```